# Скрывать div в случае если он пустой

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Задача стоит скрывать div  в случае если в нем нет содержимого. Как только в нем появляется содержимое, div сразу должен отображаться на сайте. Подскажите варианты решения данной задачи. Есть догадки, что придется делать с помощью JS. Но пока не представляю как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так **js**:

```css
if($('.block').text() == ' '){
  $('.block').css({'display': 'none'});
} else {
  $('.block').css({'display': 'block'});
}
```

```html
<p class="block"></p>

  <p class="block">Если есть текст, то блок виден</p>
```

Или так **css**:

```css
block:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="block"></p>

  <p class="block">Если есть текст, то блок виден</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ответ есть по этой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery) (с использованием JQuery):

```
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}
```

Так же можно использовать чистый [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455112/how-to-hide-remove-a-div-when-empty):

```
div:empty { display: none }
```